# Candy store with eggs

Tags: combinatorics

> The owner of a candy shop has 11 hollow chocolate eggs in his display, all of the same size but different weights of 1 lb, 2 lbs,… 11 lbs respectively. Each of them is marked with a different sticker, so that they are distinguishable. A customer, intending to buy one egg, claims that he knows all the individual weights. The owner, being rather suspicious, asks him to guess the egg that weighs 1 lb. For this reason, he gave him an empty plastic bag that can hold up to exactly 11 lbs, otherwise it will be torn and can’t be used. Please describe the strategy of the customer in order to demonstrate which one is the egg of 1 lb. What is the minimum number of uses of the plastic bag and which eggs will he put inside it in each use?

With any 5 eggs the bag will be torn.

With any 4 eggs, the bag will also be torn except from the cases 1,2,3,4 and 1,2,3,5.

With any 3 eggs, the bag will be torn except from 16 out of 165 cases, of which only 4 do not contain the egg of 1 lb.

With any 2 eggs, the bag will be torn except from 25 out of 55 cases (only 9 containing the egg of 1 lb) and obviously with only 1 egg it will not be torn.

But how do we identify the egg of 1 lb in the least number of uses of the bag?

Comment: @Shaun: I have calculated all the above combinations and eliminated the ones that are >11 lbs (see above: "with any....", marking also the ones that contain / do not contain the egg of 1 lb.

Comment: Obviously, if we are in one of the two cases of 4 eggs together, where the bag is not torn, it means that one of the 4 eggs is the one we are looking for.

Comment: Nice problem... but no ideas! I'm breaking my head over this!

Comment: 1. does he have unlimited supply of plastic bag? 2. if bag is torn what happen to eggs are they still intact??

Comment: @NewGuy: No, only one plastic bag. Once it is torn, that's it! Yes, the eggs are intact if the bag is torn.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  The customer cannot actually determine the weight of any egg, *except* by putting eggs into the bag?  I don't see how this is even remotely doable with one bag.  You have to put at least two eggs into the bag to learn anything, and it could break right then and there.  You can't possibly tell from that which egg is the one-pound egg.  (Those are pretty heavy eggs if they're hollow and one weighs $11$ pounds, incidentally!)

Comment: Or is the customer just trying to *demonstrate* that they know which egg is the one-pound egg?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, the customer claims that he knows which egg is the one-pound and the shop owner asks him to demonstrate it by using the bag.

Comment: So: Can we assume that the customer knows how much each egg weighs, and will demonstrate that knowledge by using the bag to prove that a given egg is the one-pound egg?

Comment: @BrianTung: Yes. The customer claims that he knows the weight of each egg and the candy store owner, in order to verify this, asks him to demonstrate to him which is the one-pound egg. The customer must demonstrate this by using the plastic bag and various combinations of eggs.

Comment: I believe he must start by putting together the eggs 1,2,3,4 and then 1,2,3,5 and since the bag is not torn, we deduce that one of them (common to both weighings) must be the one-pound egg. So now we have 1, 2, 3. But maybe you have some better idea!

Comment: That bounds it to 7 uses, since 1/2/3/4, 1/2/3/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9, and 1/10 prove that the one-pound egg is what it says it is.  That's probably not best, though.

Comment: Or maybe, since he knows 4 & 5, he puts together 4, 5 and 2 to show that this one is not 3 (otherwise we would have 4+5+3 = 12 and the bag would be torn). Then he must do the same with 4,5,1. Then we are left with two, of which, one is 1. How do we choose the one-pound?

Comment: And then he puts 4, 6, 1 = 11. The one he claims is 6, can only be 6 or >6, since we already know which ones are 1,2,3,4,5. (not exactly which is which, but all of them are <6). Also the one he claims is 4, can only be either 4 or 5. If it were 5, then the bag would be torn, since we would have >11. What do you think? I believe it is 5 uses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** here's a two-use strategy that doesn't involve breaking the bag: The customer bags together α/β/γ/δ and shows that the bag is intact. They then bag together α/ε/ζ and show that the bag is intact.

Now, let's set Ω=α+β+γ+δ+ε+ζ. On the one hand, Ω is the sum of six different numbers, so it must be $\geq 21 (=1+2+3+4+5+6)$. On the other hand, since α+β+γ+δ $\leq11$ (from the first bagging) and ε+ζ+α $\leq11$ (from the second bagging), we have α+β+γ+δ+ε+ζ+α = Ω+α $\leq22$. But Ω$\geq21$ and Ω+α$\leq22$ together imply α $=1$.  (Many thanks to Joffan in the comments for this easier argument!)

---

(For posterity, here's my initial four-use strategy: our customer bags together α/β/γ/δ and shows that the bag is intact, then bags together α/β/γ/ε and shows that the bag is intact.  Since the only two four-egg bags that don't break the bag are 1/2/3/4 and 1/2/3/5, we now have two known sets: we know that {α, β, γ} are {1,2,3} in some order, and we know that {δ, ε} are {4,5} in some order (though we haven't differentiated members of those sets).

Next, the customer bags together δ/ζ and shows that the bag remains intact; since δ is either 4 or 5, then ζ must be either 6 or 7.

Finally, the customer tries to bag β/γ/ζ and shows that the bag breaks.  Any combination of two eggs from the set {1,2,3} with 6 would be 'good' and not break the bag; only the combination {2,3,7} can break it.  This proves that ζ is 7 and that {β, γ} are {2,3} in some order, and therefore that α is egg 1.)

Comment: Very cool! I missed the idea of deliberately breaking the bag on the last try.

Comment: Very nice! For the two-weighing proof, the lightest six eggs weigh 21 lb so the repeated egg must be 1 lb to keep to the 22 lb limit

Comment: Steven Stadnicki: The 4-weighing proof was very clear to me. Now for the 2-weighings: He puts together α,ε,ζ but it turns out that ε=4, so he has got one of the 4 that he has already weighted, right? (unless he did 1,2,3,5). In this case, why can't it be 2,3,6? It also doesn't break the bag. Actually I don't understand how he deduces that one must be at least 4.

Comment: @NhungHuyen Joffan's proof for the two-bag solution is better than mine, but to try and better explain my own: {α,β,γ,δ} _must_ contain all of {1,2,3}, since it's either {1,2,3,4} or {1,2,3,5}. Therefore, neither ε or ζ can be 3. (Or 2 or 1, for that matter.)

Comment: @Joffan That's a great argument! Do you mind if I amend my post to use it?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: So he first weights 1,2,3,5 and the bag doesn't break, and then he puts 4,6 plus one of the ALREADY weighted, which can only be 1, since the bag does not break. Is this what you are saying? I am a bit confused with the letters alpha blah blah :)

Comment: @NhungHuyen Exactly so. We don't 'know' that the first weighing was 1,2,3,5 before the second weighing, but that's the only answer that can work.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Actually the customer knows all the weights, but he wants to "demonstrate" them using the combinations. So he picks the ones that he knows before hand that will work.

Comment: Yes, but I'm writing this from the perspective of the person the customer is trying to convince, so 'we' don't know that; we have to be proven it.

Comment: Ha, of course Steven, feel free to use.

Comment: Great job guys! Thanks for the clear explanations!